# Ionic product Image loading

Tags: ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api, frameworks

I am developing a shopping app using web API,
But getting issues like whenever app open 
It will take to much time to load products.
Maybe from product image will take time to render
, any idea how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

U can improve a performance of your app by doing following steps

1. Use pagination(i.e load 10 or 15 product from web api) on scroll
2. Maintain low size images at server so it could load fast.
3. Show a busy image while the actual image is downloading, and when the image is downloaded, remove busy image and show the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 - use ion-infinite-scroll 
2 - lazy load the images
3 - use image cache
```